# SQL Server query not matching for a varbinary type column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using this queries below to validate a user.

This query works perfectly fine in SQL Server and in my Asp.Net website.

```
SELECT * 
FROM AdminUsers 
WHERE username = 'admin' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
  AND Password = (SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'admin123'))
```

However when I put it in Asp.net/ C# code as :

```
dbManager.Command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM AdminUsers 
WHERE username= @UserName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND
Password = (SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', @Password))";

dbManager.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", username);
dbManager.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

reader = dbManager.GetDataReader();
if (reader.Read() == true)
{ //USER VALIDATED }
```

This does not match so not sure how to assign the password parameter so it works, just to confirm password entered is correct. And `Password` datatype in SQL Server table is `VarBinary`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "not matching".

Comment: As Marc said, you should not reinvent security practices or implement naively. SHA1 is fast and relatively weak so is not a good choice for password hashing. There are a whole load of libraries that can do this for you in .Net, please use those. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data type of your `@Password` parameter is not correct.

In your first example, 'admin123' is a `varchar` ascii string.

In your .net code `@Password` is a string, so is set to type `nvarchar` unicode string by default. These hash to different values, i.e.:

```
select hashbytes('SHA1', 'admin123')
select hashbytes('SHA1', N'admin123')
```

returns

```
0xF865B53623B121FD34EE5426C792E5C33AF8C227
0xB7BC3A1B04D9E165C6762B0A1CDE5226DF5B6A6A
```

You need to set it to a `varchar` SqlDbType:

```
dbManager.Command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM AdminUsers 
WHERE  username= @UserName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND
Password=(SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1',@Password))";

dbManager.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", username);
dbManager.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password)
    .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;

reader = dbManager.GetDataReader();
if (reader.Read() == true)
{ //USER VALIDATED }
```

Comment: Thank you for that, one question reading the comments above , is this weak approach to use for setting passwords?

Answer (score 1):

`@userName` and `@Password` are both `nvarchar`. `HASHBYTES` is very sensitive to `varchar` vs `nvarchar`; in your working example, `'admin123'` is `varchar`. You'll need to explicitly specify those parameters as `varchar` (by setting `.DbType = System.Data.DbType.AnsiString`), or (preferable) use `nvarchar` throughout (too late for that if already hashed). Note: `HASHBYTES` by itself probably isn't a great choice for cryptography.